# the space btw the numeric order and the table/figure name in list of table/figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I know there are similar questions of this in the community - however, none of the solutions work in my case. I am writing my dissertation and am using the latex cls from school. However, after I compiled my work, the space btw the numbers and the table/figure name is very close.
Example pictures are [image: list of table][image: list of figure]

The specific codes in the cls file for *list of figures* and *list of tables* are attached as well.

Thanks so much for any help!! I appreciate it tons.

```
\def\@listoffigures{%
  \clearpage
  \markboth{Figure}{Figure}
  \thispagestyle{tocheadings}
  \@startchapter{LIST OF FIGURES}
  \vspace*{14pt}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{Figure \hfill Page}
  \protect\nopagebreak\sloppy\pagestyle{lofextraheadings}\@mydouble\@starttoc{\ext@figure} 


\def\@listoftables{%
  \clearpage
  \markboth{Table}{Table}
  \thispagestyle{tocheadings}
  \@startchapter{LIST OF TABLES}
  \vspace*{14pt}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{Table \hfill Page}
  \protect\nopagebreak\sloppy\pagestyle{lotextraheadings}\@mydouble\@starttoc{\ext@table}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer is to use the `tocloft` package. Along the lines:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{7em}  % change 7em to suit
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{7em}  %  ""
```

which changes the space for `fig`ure and `tab`le numbers.

Read the manual (`texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Comment: thanks so much Peter! Yes it works!!